# converting integers to binary etc in javafx without using predefined methods

Tags: javafx

I have to write an application in JavaFX that converts between binary, hexadecimal and decimal numbers using three textfields. I managed to do the required layout and the app does what it's supposed to do, but I used predefined methods (Integer.toHexString etc) which is prohibited. I did it only as a prototype, so now that I know that everything else is okay, how can I go ahead and do the conversions without these methods?

Here's the part of the code, in which t1, t2 and t3 are textfields for decimal, hexadecimal and binary respectively.

EDIT: Alright, so I managed to figure it out! I only have one more tiny problem: In the binary field, I don't know how to restrict the input to only 0 or 1. For the sake of simplicity, I only copied the code for the third textfield.

EDIT 2: I got it to some extent, but it doesn't work in all cases. If the number starts with something other than 1, it's still going to convert it. It breaks in some cases, so I guess it's partially correct. Can anyone help please?

```
t3.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {

                int decimal = 0;
                int power = 0;
                int bin = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText());

                while (bin != 0) {
                    if (bin % 10 > 1) {
                        break;
                    } else {//binary
                        int tmp = bin % 10;
                        decimal += tmp * Math.pow(2, power);
                        bin = bin / 10;
                        power++;
                    }
                }

   t1.setText(String.format("%d", decimal));

   char hex[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
   String st = "";
   while (decimal > 0) {
    int y = decimal % 16;
    st = hex[y] + st;
    decimal = decimal / 16;
    t2.setText(st);
     }
   }
 });
```

Comment: I would imagine that the remaining part is pretty much the whole point of your homework assignment. You should probably try to implement at least one of these methods and post back if it doesn't work and you can't debug it yourself. If you need a "getting started" hint, try the method that parses a binary string first: iterate through the characters starting from the last, and build up the total value as you go. (If you really want to cheat, you could always just look at the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/jdk/file/935758609767/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java))